# Remove MetaData from Avro KAFKA Messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, message-queue, avro, greenplum

I am trying to sync data from Avro KAFKA messages into the target table in Greenplum using GPKAFKA version 2 but the data types are also being inserted with the actual value in the columns.

I am using UI for Apache KAFKA where all the topics are displayed along with Schema Registry and Debezium source connector.

I am trying to remove the meta data being displayed in the Avro KAFKA message but I am unable to do that.

Avro KAFKA Message (actual):

```json
{
    "key1": "39",
    "col1": {
        "int": 1
    },
    "col2": {
        "string": "def"
    },
    "col3": {
        "string": "ghi"
    },
    "col4": {
        "string": "jkl"
    },
    "instance_id": {
        "string": "009"
    }
}
```

Avro KAFKA Message (desired):

```json
{
    "key1": "39",
    "col1": 1,
    "col2": "def",
    "col3": "ghi",
    "col4": "jkl",
    "instance_id": "009"
}
```